# Spring Security + CAS + Tomcat: Do not listen to the url: /login/cas

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, cas

I'm learning Spring security. I have developed an application that authenticates by CAS. I started from the example of this tutorial: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-cas-sso.

The content of the **WebSecurityConfig** file is:

```java
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSecurityConfig.class);
    private SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter;
    private LogoutFilter logoutFilter;
    private CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider;
    private ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

    @Autowired
    public WebSecurityConfig(SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter, LogoutFilter logoutFilter,
                             CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider,
                             ServiceProperties serviceProperties) {
        this.logoutFilter = logoutFilter;
        this.singleSignOutFilter = singleSignOutFilter;
        this.serviceProperties = serviceProperties;
        this.casAuthenticationProvider = casAuthenticationProvider;
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/secured", "/login").authenticated()
          .and()
          .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
          .and()
          .addFilterBefore(singleSignOutFilter, CasAuthenticationFilter.class)
          .addFilterBefore(logoutFilter, LogoutFilter.class)
          .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/exit/cas");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(casAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(casAuthenticationProvider));
    }

    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        CasAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new CasAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        entryPoint.setLoginUrl("http://cas-docker:7080/cas/login");
        entryPoint.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        return entryPoint;
    }

}
```

The content of the **Spring application** file is:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class CasSecuredApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CasSecuredApplication.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(CasSecuredApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CasSecuredApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationFilter casAuthenticationFilter(
      AuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
      ServiceProperties serviceProperties) throws Exception {
        CasAuthenticationFilter filter = new CasAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        filter.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        return filter;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServiceProperties serviceProperties() {
        logger.info("service properties");
        ServiceProperties serviceProperties = new ServiceProperties();
        serviceProperties.setService("https://tomcat-docker:8443/cas-secured-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/login/cas");
        serviceProperties.setSendRenew(false);
        return serviceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public TicketValidator ticketValidator() {
        return new Cas30ServiceTicketValidator("http://cas-docker:7080/cas");
    }

    @Bean
    public CasAuthenticationProvider casAuthenticationProvider(
      TicketValidator ticketValidator,
      ServiceProperties serviceProperties) {
        CasAuthenticationProvider provider = new CasAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setServiceProperties(serviceProperties);
        provider.setTicketValidator(ticketValidator);
        provider.setUserDetailsService(
          s -> new User("test@test.com", "Mellon", true, true, true, true,
          AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("ROLE_ADMIN")));
        provider.setKey("CAS_PROVIDER_LOCALHOST_8900");
        return provider;
    }


    @Bean
    public SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler() {
        return new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public LogoutFilter logoutFilter() {
        LogoutFilter logoutFilter = new LogoutFilter("https://tomcat-docker:8443/logout", securityContextLogoutHandler());
        logoutFilter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/logout/cas");
        return logoutFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter() {
        SingleSignOutFilter singleSignOutFilter = new SingleSignOutFilter();
        singleSignOutFilter.setLogoutCallbackPath("/exit/cas");
        singleSignOutFilter.setIgnoreInitConfiguration(true);
        return singleSignOutFilter;
    }

}
```

When I access **/login** a redirection is made to the CAS protected area. Then, the login screen is displayed, I enter the name and password and click on the login session button. After that, CAS redirects to this url:

```
https://tomcat-docker:8443/cas-secured-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/login/cas?ticket=ST-10-23dDew2ztSMwkbEXgtDC-9086a9962d01
```

After this, the following error is obtained:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri May 21 10:24:12 UTC 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
```

This link https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/cas.html mentions that the filter is always listening for requests to **/login/cas**.

Why doesn't the filter listen for /login/cas and continue with the authentication process? Is something missing in the code?

**Update**:

The CAS server log shows the following:

```
2021-05-21 12:43:56,544 INFO [org.apereo.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] - <Audit trail record BEGIN

=============================================================

WHO: casuser


WHAT: ST-18-snPFz6n5AdakHvBpROlf-9086a9962d01 for https://localhost:8443/login/cas


ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED


APPLICATION: CAS


WHEN: Fri May 21 12:43:56 UTC 2021


CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 172.19.0.1


SERVER IP ADDRESS: 172.19.0.6


=============================================================
```

In the properties file, I have put:

```java
server.servlet.contextPath=/cas-secured-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

The CAS server configuration is default. I have not touched it.

Why does the Cas server say it is listening on **https://localhost:8443/login/cas**? Is it necessary to configure the CAS server?

Comment: your context is cas-secured-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. Is it right? Also why do you use context for spring boot app. I guess it is not mandatory

Comment: When I deploy in tomcat it creates this entry point: http://tomcat-docker:8084/cas-secured-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ and it is displayed the public page containing a link to access the CAS protected area.

Comment: You have configuration like http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers( "/secured", "/login"). Also it means that  tomcat-docker:8084/secured,  tomcat-docker:8084/login. Maybe that is the reason why it fails. If you do not specify the context.

Comment: Sorry, I'm lost. How can I specify the context? Is it adding this property? server.servlet.contextPath=/cas-secured-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: yes you can add server.servlet.context-path=/cas-secured-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Comment: @Gurkanİlleez  I have updated the question. I have noticed that in the CAS server log it is listening for  https://localhost:8443/login/cas. Is it a CAS configuration problem?

Comment: By default spring boot does not use context path. Maybe you can configure serviceProperties.setService("https://tomcat-docker:8443/cas-secured-app-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/login/cas"); to serviceProperties.setService("https://tomcat-docker:8443/login/cas");

Comment: Can you provide more logs from the client-side of your application? You could try the following Spring Boot property `server.error.include-stacktrace=always` to print out more details about it. Since you are getting a 500 error, there should be probably an exception on your client-side.

Comment: Thank you, it was very helpful to me. The problem is in the URL used by the method: ```ticketValidator()```. I was using a wrong port.